# JQuery.ajax error 400 bad request with Struts

Tags: java, jquery, ajax, struts

I have a website, made with Struts1, java and JSPs, and I need to get datas from a webservice dynamically.
I call my java method using AJAX in my JSP, but I get an Error 400: bad request no matter what I try.
So here is my Javascript function in my JSP:

```
var panierSansFares=new Array();

function myFunction(){

        $.ajax({
            url: "myPath/getFares.do?method=doGet",
            type: 'GET',
            dataType: 'json',
            contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8", // this
            data: 'panierSansFares='+JSON.stringify(panierSansFares),
            success: function(res) {
                alert(res);
            }
        });
  }
```

Note that panierSansFares in an array of objects, and it is not empty when the function is called.
And in my STRUTS, the action:

```
<action path="/getFares" 
            type="myPath.GetFaresServlet"
            scope="request" >
        </action>
```

And lastly, my java code:

```
public class GetFaresServlet  extends Action {
   private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

   protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, ActionMapping actionMapping) throws IOException {
                  /**Some stuff**/

   }
}
```

My Error 400 comes from the Struts, because I can see a "Invalid path was requested" error in Chrome developer tools (network tab).

I tried to bypass Struts and just call my java directly as a servlet, but I couldn't do it, I got error404.

I've never used ajax with Struts before so I'm lacking knowledge to find where the problem is.

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I did not understand your problem but i follow this code for api call

```js
function APICall(url, methodType, data) {
    var d = $.Deferred();
    methodType = methodType || "GET";
    data = data || null;
    $.ajax({
        url: url,
        async: true,
        method: methodType,
        data: data,
        contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
        dataType: "json",
        success: function (response, status, request) {
            d.resolve(response, status, request);
        },
        error: function (error) {
            d.resolve(error.responseJSON);
        }
    });
    return d.promise();
}
APICall(url, methodType, data).done(function (response, status, request) {
    d.resolve(response, status, request);
}).fail(function (response) {
    d.resolve(response, status, request);
});
```

Comment: I figured out what is the problem: The error 400 actually comes from my Struts: I have "Invalid path was requested". However I don't get what's wrong and how to solve it